# IF OR Statements

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

How do you do an IF ... OR ... THEN statement in a Google spreadsheet?  In PHP I would do this:

```
if($C7 == "U.S.A." || $C7 == "Canada"){ ...
```

How to do the same as a spreadsheet formula?

At the moment I have

```
= IF ( C7 = "U.S.A." , "The Americas" , "Europe" )
```

I'd like to say if C7 = "U.S.A." OR "Canada"...

NB: I should have been able to (and tried extensively to) Google this, but the search engine ignores the words IF and OR

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In Google Spreadsheets, `OR` is a function (with any number of arguments), so you would write

```
IF (OR(C7 = "U.S.A."; C7 = "Canada"); "The Americas"; "Europe")
```

See the [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Avea1NXBTibYdG1fcjRObDBJZEFqNFVHcXBZbGtUTEE&usp=sharing) I set up.

Also, check the [Google Spreadsheets function list](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs&tab=1240291).

Note that my example code uses `;` - you might have to use `,`, depending on your locale settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you have longer statement,you can use `regexmatch()` instead.

```
regexmatch(C7,"(U.S.A.|Canada|Other_area_name|Other_area_name2|Other_area_name3)")
```

separated by adding `|` symbol.

For more complicated use,see the [official documents](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292).